# Responder un correo con todo el hilo usando Mailkit

Tags: c#, email, imap

Estoy respondiendo un mensaje de correo y estoy utilizando la clase ReplyVisitor que esta en la documentación de MailKit, pero necesito agregarle al Body un HTML de respuesta pero conservando el hilo del correo, en la variable visitor se retorna el mensaje de respuesta y ha esta quiero agregarle un texto personalizado (var bodyRespuesta) al inicio del cuerpo del mensaje que esta en el visitor.Body, como puedo lograr esto?

http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Frequently-Asked-Questions.htm#Reply

```
public static MimeMessage ReplyMenssageNewCase(MimeMessage message, MailboxAddress from, bool replyToAll, string caseID, string NameResponsable, string emailResponsable)
    {
        var visitor = new ReplyVisitor();
        var reply = new MimeMessage();

        reply.From.Add(from);

        // reply to the sender of the message
        if (message.ReplyTo.Count > 0)
        {
            reply.To.AddRange(message.ReplyTo);
        }
        else if (message.From.Count > 0)
        {
            reply.To.AddRange(message.From);
        }
        else if (message.Sender != null)
        {
            reply.To.Add(message.Sender);
        }

        if (replyToAll)
        {
            // include all of the other original recipients 
            reply.To.AddRange(message.To);
            reply.Cc.AddRange(message.Cc.Mailboxes.Where(x => x.Address != from.Address));
            // Al responsable del caso se le envia como copia oculta la respuesta.
            MailboxAddress mailbox = new MailboxAddress(NameResponsable, emailResponsable);
            InternetAddress internet = mailbox;
            reply.Bcc.Add(internet);
        }

        // set the reply subject
        if (!message.Subject.StartsWith("Re: [Empresa][Ticket]", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            reply.Subject = "Re: [Empresa][Ticket][" + caseID + "]" + message.Subject;
        else
            reply.Subject = message.Subject;

        // construct the In-Reply-To and References headers
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.MessageId))
        {
            reply.InReplyTo = message.MessageId;
            foreach (var id in message.References)
                reply.References.Add(id);
            reply.References.Add(message.MessageId);
        }

        visitor.Visit(message);

        var builder = new BodyBuilder();
        var bodyRespuesta = "<div>respuesta</div>";


        builder.HtmlBody = string.Format(bodyRespuesta);

        reply.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();

        // La idea es que se envie el visitor.Body y en la parte inciar de este visitor.Body debe ir el mensaje que actualmente se le envia. 
        //reply.Body = visitor.Body ?? builder.ToMessageBody();

        return reply;
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Actualizo la pregunta